# Can't find Matlab libraries with find_library command

Tags: cmake

I issue the following commands:

```
find_file(MATLAB_ROOT matlab $ENV{ProgramW6432})
set(MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY ${MATLAB_ROOT}/extern/lib/win64/microsoft)

find_library(MATLAB_MEX_LIB mex
  ${MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY}
)
```

But it fails with `MATLAB_MEX_LIB-NOTFOUND`. My path seems correct I can easily retrieve the library file with the following command:

```
find_file(LIB_FILE libmex.lib ${MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY})
```

I'm working in Windows 7 with cmake version 2.8.9

Comment: The [`find_matlab`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindMatlab.html) module of cmake >= 3.3 does everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I used `--trace` option in cmake and saw that there are missing suffixes for the `find_library` command:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES lib )
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .dll.a .a )
```

So I changed the path to:

```
set(MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY ${MATLAB_ROOT}/bin/win64)
```

And invoked the following commands:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .dll .dll.a .a)
find_library(MATLAB_MEX_LIB mex
             PATHS ${MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY}
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

This time all went fine. Thanks for the support Fraser!

Comment: No worries.  Good you got it in the end!

Answer (score 0):

When you do [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library), the search prepends [`${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX) to each of the provided names (and also appends [`${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX)).

On Windows, `${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}` is empty; on Unix it is "lib", so you'll need to prepend the "lib" to your search name for Windows only.  You can cover both cases by using the long-hand version of `find_library`:

```
find_library(MATLAB_MEX_LIB
                NAMES mex libmex
                PATHS ${MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY}
                NO_DEFAULT_PATH  # Avoid searching outside MATLAB_LIBS_DIRECTORY
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it out but It didn't work, still nothing found, altought the file is there. Is there a way to debug the search process?